# Is there a way for pilots to report difficulties and challenges experienced during a flight, to the next flight crew?

Tags: aircraft-operations

My question is reflected in the title - is there an official, international system for commercial pilots to report difficulties and challenges faced during a flight to the next and future crew? Ideally, such a system should also require the next crew to review recent entries into it. Does something like it exist and if so, how strictly is it followed?

Comment: _system where pilots report difficulties and challenges experienced_ : that depends *a)* on regulations (honest response is "yes there is") *b)* whether they are actually followed (depends on several factors) and *c)* whether who experienced the problem considers it worth to point out (You won't report windshear in a paper every once you land in those conditions). It's not because it's written in an official paper that everyone applies, and it's not always the pilot to blame. We're talking about the entire world, not USA alone. If the weather radar is not available would you cancel the flight?

Comment: @KarlStephen Thanks, that makes sense. But I feel challenges that involve the plane losing altitude are certainly worth documenting. Hindsight is 20/20 of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation about an accident whose investigation is still on-going, which is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Close if you must, but the question is about the reporting system and the facts that are stated (presence of third pilot for example) are undisputed.

Comment: I don't think this is either opinion-based, nor accident speculation, as the discussion on MCAS, the Lion Air accident, and the Ethiopian Air accident, are merely preamble to what you're actually asking. I've made an edit to highlight this.

Comment: Thanks, the edit is an improvement.

Comment: I have removed all of the commentary from the question - with it, this question is borderline accident speculation which we don't support. Without it, this is IMO a good question.

Comment: The ASRS in the US?

Answer (score 3):

"Difficulties" are hard to quantify. And it's questionable whether a difficulty experienced by one flight is even relevant to the next. Many difficulties are transient in nature (eg: weather, crew, cargo loading).

However, there is what is known as an [Acceptable Defered Defect](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Acceptable_Deferred_Defect):

> An identified aircraft defect which has been assessed as being within the requirements of the Minimum Equipment List (MEL) or Configuration Deviation List and has had rectification deferred within a specified limit. Also referred to as a CFD (Carried Forward Defect)

This is used to notify future aircrew of a specific aircraft of any defects which, although does not require the aircraft to be removed from service, may be relevant to its operation.

Pilots *absolutely* check this before every flight.

Comment: Thanks, this only holds for the United States?

Comment: Also, is this only inter airline or also intra airline if the other airline is flying the exact same model?

Comment: Last question, I'm sure most pilots check it, but are they required to check it by protocol?

Comment: I think this is talking about *per aircraft* defects.